# The function in R that can calculate how many times a digit appears in a vector

Tags: r

So, for example, if I have a vector `x <- c(11, 2354, 55, 432, 1112, 320)`, the function should return a vector that indicates how many times the digits 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 have appeared in `x`.

For 'x', the expected counts for digits 0,1,2..9 would be c(1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), because, 0 only appeared once in 320, 1 appeared 2 (in 11) + 3 (in 1112) = 5 and so on.

I am trying to make function like this, but I am not really good at R. Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
f <- function(x){
 if(is.vector(x) & length(x) > 0) {
 z <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 n <- c(nchar(x))
 for(i in range(length(x))) {
   for(d in range(n[i])) {
     for (j in range(1:10)) {
       if(x[i]%%10 == j) {
         z <- replace(z, z == z[j], z[j]+1)
       }
     }
   x <- replace(x, x == x[i], x[i]%/%10)
  }
 }return(z) 
}
}
```

Comment: *"where the each element -- number of digits in previous vector"* I don't understand your expected output. Why is `y[1] = 1` for `x[1] = 11`? Why is `y[2] = 5` for `x[2] = 2354`? Can you explain the logic for those two examples? To get the number of digits `nchar` might be a possibility. E.g. `nchar(123)` returns `3`.

Comment: and why is the `y` vector longer than the `x` vector? shouldn't they be of the same length?

Comment: really unclear how to get from your input to your output. please help to clarify

Comment: @MauritsEvers , y[1] equal to the number of "0" in elements of x -- it exist only in x[6] = 320 etc.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it becomes clearer to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have constructed this function. This function will give how many digits of 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 appears in a vector as needed. The "main engine" of this function is the `str_count()` from library `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
count_digits = function(x){
  y <- rep(0, 10)
  for(digit in 0:9){
    y[digit+1] <- sum(str_count(x,as.character(digit)))
  }
  y
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I am not really understand where are mistakes in my code, may be you can help with it too?

Comment: "Error in replace(x, x == x[i], x[i]%/%10) : 
  unused arguments (x == x[i], x[i]%/%10)"

What does it mean?

Comment: I did not know of str_count(). Good answer. You just need to do str_count(paste(x,collapse=""),as.character(0:9))

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that uses base R and avoids for loops.

```
x <- c(11, 2354, 55, 432, 1112, 320)

countintegers <- function(x) {
    xpasted <- paste(x, collapse ='')
    xsplit <- strsplit(xpasted, '')
    xtable <- table(xsplit)
    empty <- table(seq(0,9)) - 1
    result <- sapply(names(empty), function(n) xtable[n] + empty[n])
    result[is.na(result)] <- 0
    as.integer(result)
}

countintegers(x)

#1 5 4 3 2 3 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use some regex for this, by pasting all the numbers into one string and then counting how many characters are removed by `gsub()` if a digit is replaced with "":

```
digitCounter <- function(x) {
   x <- paste(x, collapse = "")
   l <- vector()
   for(i in 0:9) {l[i+1] <- nchar(x) - nchar(gsub(i, "", x))}
   return(l)
}
```